# dotNET framework has been installed by php

Tags: php, .net, frameworks

I've wrote a web application with php and I just want to secure the source code.

My questions is; How can I find out that .net framework has been installed on the server, by php?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "item process".

Comment: ops!  i mean the process tab in windows task manager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply try to create an instance of the dotnet object you want to use, e.g.

```
<?php
try {
    $o = new DOTNET("mscorlib", "System.Object");
    echo 'success';
}
catch(com_exception $e) {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

see http://docs.php.net/class.dotnet

Comment: thank u so much but ,Fatal error: Class 'DOTNET' not found in F:\xampp\htdocs\temp\dotnetframework\DNFMWFinder.php on line 61 - so what should i do ?

Comment: Looks like you need another build of php, one with the `com-dotnet` option enabled.

Comment: How can i download this bulid ? I really need it

Comment: The packages provided by http://windows.php.net/ seem to have the com-dotnet module built-in.